# Neo4j: Get all nodes in a graph, using RESTful call

Tags: neo4j, nodes, cypher, restful-url

I am looking for an equivalent restful service call for a cypher query.

```
start n=node:node_audo_index("term:*") return n;
```

Any thoughts on it?

Answer (score 3):

A `GET` request to `http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/auto/node/?query=term:*` should do it. See https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-find-node-by-query.

But the question is why do you want to use REST api in favour of Cypher? I can not see a good reason for this.

Comment: this answers my question. I still want to use rest api with cypher plugin, in this case I don't even need cypher equivalent query for REST API, i can make use of cypher query in a REST call.

Comment: I too need REST for my web application.

Comment: One (current) example of why one might need the REST api is when using the test harness to test server side plugins or unmanaged extensions. The test harness does not obviously support cypher execution. I *think* this will change in version 2.3 currently at M2